# Looping Regex with Replace

Tags: c#, regex

In C#, I'm working with a small text file of variable length (it may have 4-6 lines).

Each line contains a repeating expression, followed by a 2-digit number and a colon and some concluding information.

For example:

```
some information 27: some other information
some information 28: some other information
some information 29: some other information
```

I need to remove all the characters up to and including the colon ':', leaving just the concluding information.

I have tried using a Regex expression as shown below. It correctly handles the first line in the file, but only the first line.

```cs
private static string ModifyTheInformation(string str)
{
    string pattern = "^[^:\r\n]+:[ \t]*";
    string replacement = "";

    if (Regex.IsMatch(str, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline))
    {
        str = Regex.Replace(str, pattern, replacement);
    }
}
```

I need the Regex to ***loop*** through the file and affect all the lines.
I have also tried using the Regex Match match method and match.NextMatch.
For example:

```cs
Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
Match m = r.Match(str);
while (m.Success)
{
    //try something
}
```

However, an instance variable does not offer the 'Replace' method.

Please suggest how I may use a Regex expression, which both *Loops* and can *Replace* the specified characters in each line of a text file.

Comment: You already have it, `str = Regex.Replace(str, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.Multiline)`. You omitted `RegexOptions.Multiline`,  but used it in `Regex.IsMatch`. You do not need the `Regex.IsMatch` at all here. Use `private static string ModifyTheInformation(string str)
{ return Regex.Replace(str, "^[^:\r\n]+:[ \t]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline); }`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew That is exactly what I needed. I have only used Regex a few times and wasn't aware that I could omit the IsMatch portion and have it affect the entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omitted `RegexOptions.Multiline` in the call to `Regex.Replace`, but kept it in the `Regex.IsMatch` call, that is your mistake.

You do not need to check for a regex match with the `Regex.IsMatch` because `Regex.Replace` returns the unchanged string if no matches were detected.

Use

```cs
private static string ModifyTheInformation(string str)
{
    return Regex.Replace(str, "^[^:\r\n]+:[ \t]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B%5E%3A%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2B%3A%5B%20%5Ct%5D*&i=some%20information%2027%3A%20some%20other%20information%0D%0Asome%20information%2028%3A%20some%20other%20information%0D%0Asome%20information%2029%3A%20some%20other%20information&r=&o=m).

However, it seems all you need is to read the input file line by line and remove all before the first colon with a mere

```
line.Substring(line.IndexOf(":") + 1).Trim()
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/py1UBb).

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need a regex here - simply split each line of text on ':', e.g.

```
    string x = "some information 27: some other information";
    Console.WriteLine(x.Split(new char[]{':'}, 2)[1]);
```